# SO contacts Facebook server, what consequences if I block it?

Tags: discussion, privacy, facebook

While loading [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714953/how-to-use-the-psql-command-to-list-create-use-and-examine-databases), I briefly saw this in my status bar:

> Downloading from graph.facebook.com

The full request:

```
GET /100001936071639/picture?type=large HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.facebook.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
DNT: 1
Referer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14714953
Cookie: <edited for brevity, lots of stuff>
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I am not a fan of Facebook receiving information about me. My SO account is not linked to a Facebook account for authentication, obviously.

**QUESTION:** If I block `facebook.com`, will some Stack Overflow features stop working, or silently fail?

Comment: AFAIK, it's only for the 'Do you know someone who can answer this? Share by bla bla bla <insert facebook thumb here>'

Comment: Could be, but it's also for [this user's avatar](https://graph.facebook.com/100001936071639/picture?type=large). No harm done if you block it I'd say.

Answer (score 7):

I might not have found all occurrences of Facebook URL usages, but from my short investigation it seems that requests to Facebook are only made to load the profile pictures of people who created their Stack Exchange account via a Facebook account.

So it seems that the only thing that will fail is: **Some users' profile picture will not show up.**

*Don't hesitate to correct me if you find new cases where requests are made.*